# Mysql invalid argument

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason the code below provides me with the following error: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). I tested the query in PHPmyadmin and the query works on its own. For some reason it doesn't work in the context if this php document. Are there any specific mistakes that are leading to this?

Thanks

```
  <!Doctype <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th> Course </th>
        <th> Instructor </th>
    <?php
        $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname = 282exam; host = localhost", "root", "root");
        $rows = $db->query("SELECT c.Name, i.Name
                            FROM course c
                            JOIN instructor i ON i.CId = c.Code");
        foreach ($rows as $row){
            ?>
            <tr> 
                <td> <?php print $row["c.Name"] ?></td>
                <td> <?php print $row["i.Name"] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: start by fixing this `<!Doctype <!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: then there should not contain any spaces in `new PDO("mysql:dbname = 282exam; host = localhost"` and http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have thrown you an error about it. see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: You are only querying, no [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/pdo.exec.php)ution or [`fetch`](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetch.php)ing them

Comment: var dump gives me a value of false

Comment: wait what do you mean by no spaces?

Comment: ask the guy who gave you an answer below. I've outlined your connection error and your doctype declaration issue. so, check for errors, you're not doing that. You also didn't close your table tag.

Comment: `$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=282exam;host=localhost", "root", "root");` there, connection fixed.

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
foreach ($rows as $row){
```

do

```
while($row = $rows->fetch()){
```

(I just found out that change is optional, your way should work fine but this is how I've always done it)

And you don't need to specify the table alias in the result array

```
$row["Name"]
```

But you should specify an alias for each column if they're both the same...

```
SELECT c.Name as cname, i.Name as iname

$row["cname"] , $row["iname"]
```

Also, what Fred said:

> then there should not contain any spaces in new PDO("mysql:dbname =
>   282exam; host = localhost" and
>   php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php would have thrown you an
>   error about it. see the manual php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php –
>   Fred -ii-

In other words: Change this to..

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=282exam;host=localhost", "root", "root");
```

AND

- Missing `<doctype>` at the top that may cause errors
- Missing `</table>`

Also, you're using `<th>` tags but no table header tags. Check out [one of these links](https://www.google.com/search?q=table%20html%20syntax&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to figure out the correct table syntax.

Comment: and `Name` now stands for `c.Name` or `i.Name`?

Comment: `PDOStatement` implements `Traversable` so you can loop over the result of the query without having to fetch rows separately.

Comment: there are so many syntax errors in that question, it's not funny. missing a closing `</table>` tag too.

Comment: Hey guys sorry for the syntax errors. I'm confused as to why i have to fetch rows. Whats the problem with my current code? Why isn't $rows getting the rows from the database?

Comment: *"Also, what Fred said."* - that comment "could" disappear one day ;-) thanks for the mention, but the answer should contain everything that's wrong with their code. From their doctype declaration, the connection, right down to the missing `</table>` tag. Also about what KingHero said.

Comment: Yes I have read the answers and i dont understand them. Pamblams answer tells me to use fetchall, but arrays are traversable in pdo so this should work. And I don't understand what Fred said about the connection error.

Comment: ...Fred said to read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php @AlbertDorfman and [what Kinghero said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399444/mysql-invalid-argument#comment56540227_34399444)